# TraceID for a request is not travelling between services

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I am calling a microservice from a microservice and expecting the traceID (given by sleuth) initiated from base service should travel to the called services as implanted sleuth with zipkin.

Here is the call to the service

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
logger.info("ApplicationController: controllerMessage() called: " + properties.getType() +
                " " + properties2.getMode());
String uri = "http://localhost:8089/poc1/message";
//String uri = "http://google.com";
        
        
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
//headers.add("Authorization", authToken);
HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);
        
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                uri,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                request,
                String.class
            );
```

Expecting that the same traceID printed in the logs of above service will be printed in the logs of called service. In this case, same trace id should print in the logs of http://localhost:8089/poc1/message. **However this is not happening**.

Using **2.7.5 version of spring boot** and **2021.0.4 of spring cloud**.

Any clue what is wrong here?

Expecting the same traceID generated by the initial request should print in the logs of called service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating `RestTemplate` via new. Please create it as a bean and inject it to your code.

```
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate() {
  return new RestTemplate();
}
```

We're writing it in the docs with a big exclamation mark here https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/integrations.html#sleuth-http-client-rest-template-integration

Let me paste that for your convenience

> You have to register RestTemplate as a bean so that the interceptors get injected. If you create a RestTemplate instance with a new keyword, the instrumentation does NOT work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Marcin. You are right. I create the RestTemplate Bean and inject it in the code and it's worked for me. Thanks a lot for your inputs.